# IP address to trusted_host_patterns

Tags: 7

I tried to add IP address to for example : 172.20.0.3
I get this error : The provided host name is not valid for this server.

Here my settings

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^172\.20.\0.\3$',
  '^localhost$',
);
```

Comment: The HTTP host header will be a hostname, never an IP, so allowing IP addresses in `trusted_host_patterns` wouldn't make sense. They need to be hostnames or patterns to match hostnames as would be sent by the client

Comment: @Clive It would make sense if the client uses the IP address instead of the domain name, such as http://127.0.0.1/index.php

Comment: Yeah @ЕлинЙ., not sure what I meant by that

Answer (score 4):

Your regex is incorrect. You placed the second and third `\` after the `.` instead of before.

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^172\.20\.0\.3$',
  '^localhost$',
);
```